# Массив links

Tags: javascript

Доброго дня, а есть ли такой javascript что сканирует массив links и выводит ссылки на онлайн-видео? Ну к примеру,есть страница http://site.ru/ на нем есть онлайн-видео, и при выполнении данного скрипта он выводит прямую ссылку на скачивание этого видео с превьюшкой.
Просьба *сильно не пинать* только начал изучать javascript и ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.links.length; ++i)
{
    if(/_videoLink_/.test(document.links[i].href))
    {
        //вставка ссылки согласно API сайта с видео
    }
}
```

Вместо `_videoLink_` нужно выражение для ссылки на видео, например: `youtube\.com\/watch\?v=`

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите запустить скрипт локально, что бы он вывел вам ссылки на видео со страницы http://site.ru? Если так то с помощью JS сделать это будет не так то просто :) скрипт постом выше подразумевает что он будет вставлен в страницу http://site.ru